# VBA Execute batch and read/count its current line if it starts with certain string

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, progress-bar

I have a download tool made in excel. It exports .bat files and executes them. Now i wanted to add a progress bar to it.

The code below works just fine, except one thing: It does not count the current lines starting with "ping" correctly.

```
Sub DownloadWithProgressbar()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim objWshScriptExec As Object
Dim objStdOut As Object

Dim objFil3
Dim objFSO
Dim objOSF
Dim obj3liF

Dim rline As String
Dim strline As String

Dim strSearch As String
Dim currentdownloadnum As Long
Dim totaldownloadsnum As Long
Dim progresspercent As Double
Dim pctCompl As Single

Dim filepath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim fileextension As String

filepath = "D:\Eigene Dateien\"
filename = "1"
fileextension = ".bat"

strSearch = "ping"

currentdownloadnum = 0
totaldownloadsnum = 0
progresspercent = 0


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFil3 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filepath & filename & fileextension)
Do While Not objFil3.AtEndofStream
    If Left(objFil3.Readline, Len(strSearch)) = strSearch Then
        totaldownloadsnum = totaldownloadsnum + 1
    Else:

    End If
Loop
MsgBox filepath & filename & fileextension & " will download " & totaldownloadsnum & " files." & vbNewLine & "It has " & totaldownloadsnum & " lines starting with the indicator word " & Chr(34) & strSearch & Chr(34) & "."



Set objOSF = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set obj3liF = objOSF.OpenTextFile(filepath & filename & fileextension)

'Create Shellobject "cmd.exe"
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'Execute file with cmd.exe
Set objWshScriptExec = objShell.Exec(filepath & filename & fileextension)
'Create Outputobject
Set objStdOut = objWshScriptExec.StdOut

'Loop until end of file is reached
Do Until objStdOut.AtEndofStream

    'Number of current Download
    If Left(obj3liF.Readline, Len(strSearch)) = strSearch Then
        currentdownloadnum = currentdownloadnum + 1
    Else
        currentdownloadnum = currentdownloadnum
    End If

    'This line needs to stay, otherwise excel will crash. But its not used at all.
    rline = objStdOut.Readline
    If rline <> "" Then strline = strline & vbCrLf & CStr(Now) & ":" & Chr(9) & rline

'Calculate progress
progresspercent = (currentdownloadnum / totaldownloadsnum) * 100
'give progressbar variable the progress value
pctCompl = progresspercent
'Sending progress to progressbar
progress pctCompl

Loop


'Show content of file in vba message
MsgBox strline

'testing
MsgBox currentdownloadnum & " current" & vbNewLine & totaldownloadsnum & " total"

'Show download completed message
MsgBox "End of file reached: All downloads finished"
End Sub
```

**The part i need help with is this:**

```
    'Number of current Download
    If Left(obj3liF.Readline, Len(strSearch)) = strSearch Then
        currentdownloadnum = currentdownloadnum + 1
    Else
        currentdownloadnum = currentdownloadnum
    End If
```

It throws back a wrong number. In total 4 (in my example) while the file has 7 "ping"-lines. I assume its probably because its a different object, but dont know how to include this in another way into the Do Until Loop.

Total amount of lines cannot be used for this since the batch file also has empty lines and ones with other commands. For testing purposes i use "ping" as "download"-command.

MsgBox rline output:
empty or "D:\Eigene Dateien\Eigene Dokumente>ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 1>nul"
(or if other content added to .bat then this content)

MsgBox obj3liF.Readline output:
empty or "ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 1>nul"
(or if other content added to .bat then this content)

MsgBox Strline output:
[image]

Using the progress bar from this tutorial: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/progress-indicator.html
Other attempts are very welcome as well.

Comment: Can you output the `.ReadLine` strings? It would be helpful to see what's being read

Comment: Sure. Added it to my post. Did some more tests in between and sometimes i get Error 62 "Input past end of file" now for the line (MsgBox obj3liF.Readline) i just added. This kind of confirms my assumption im using the wrong object. But still no clue how else to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got two `.ReadLine`'s in the loop, If you have an odd number of line in the file, one is going to fail when you reach the end of the file.

Untested, but I suspect this is what you want

```
'Loop until end of file is reached
Do Until objStdOut.AtEndofStream
    rline = objStdOut.Readline

    'Number of current Download
    ' Based on comment, search is actually for rLine contains strSearch
    'If Left$(rline , Len(strSearch)) = strSearch Then
    If Instr(rLine, strSearch) > 0 Then
        currentdownloadnum = currentdownloadnum + 1
    End If

    If rline <> "" Then strline = strline & vbCrLf & CStr(Now) & ":" & Chr(9) & rline

    'Calculate progress
    progresspercent = (currentdownloadnum / totaldownloadsnum) * 100
    'give progressbar variable the progress value
    pctCompl = progresspercent
    'Sending progress to progressbar
    progress pctCompl
Loop
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. It throws back 0 for currentdownloadnum at the end, so doesnt count at all.

Comment: I really dont get why it doesnt count since its actually reading the file as "MsgBox rline" inside the loop proofs.

Comment: looking at your popup image the file lines begin with the file path, but you are searching for lines starting with "ping".  Perhaps use `If Instr(rLine, strSearch) > 0 Then`